# how to expose a QVariantHash variable to QtScript?

Tags: qt, qtscript

I know I can use below way to expose QStringList to QtScript, but how can I expose a QVariantHash?

```
QStringList l;
l<<"2";
QScriptValue v = qScriptValueFromSequence(&engine, l);
engine.globalObject().setProperty("v", v);
```

Answer (score 0):

For standard containers `qScriptValueFromSequence()` is running fine. For other types you probably will have to create your own conversion function, take a look at `qScriptRegisterMetaType()`.

Comment: just checked Qt Assistant. looks like it can auto convert QVariantMap type? But do you know how. Believe QVariantMap will serve the same purpose as QVariantHash. it'll be great if auto convert is supported.

Answer (score 0):

you can use engine.toStriptValue() to expose QVariantMap to QtScript

```
QVariantMap map;
map["a"] = 3;
map["b"] = 4;

QScriptValue v = engine.toScriptValue(map);
engine.globalObject().setProperty("m", v);

engine.evaluate("var h = new Haha()");
qDebug()<<engine.evaluate("h.add(m)").toString();
```